# Using annotation one-to-many not add column(hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, dao

Sorry for my english. I have 2 tables - Posts(id, namePost, Text, idCat) and Category(id, nameCat). I using `hibernate` and pattern `DAO`. I create one to many in table **Category** column `CategoryId` -> to **Posts** `idCat`. Link king of work, output information good. But when i add information in table **Posts**, column idCat dont add, it contains it's nothing in database. I cant add this column(idCat) in table Posts. I try do this many taime, but not success(

**Category**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="CATEGORY")
    public class Category {

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID", insertable=false, nullable=false)
        private int id;

        @Column(name="NAMECAT") 
        private String nameCat;

        @Column(name="INDEX") 
        private boolean index;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category")
        private Set<Posts> post;
//then get and set
```

**Posts**

```
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAMEPOST", nullable = false) 
    private String namePost;

    @Column(name="TEXT", nullable = false) 
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDCAT", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Category category;
//code
```

*interface* **PostDao**

```
public interface PostDao {
   public void addPost(Posts post);
}
```

this is **servlet**

```
String[] catarrayid = request.getParameterValues("eachcat");//get cat what user use
   String textpost = request.getParameter("textpost"); //text post
   String namepost = request.getParameter("namepost"); //name post

   if(!textpost.isEmpty() && !namepost.isEmpty() && catarrayid!=null) {
    //open session              
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
                    session.beginTransaction();

    Posts post = new Posts();
    //this value take id category               
    int id = 0;
    for(String s : catarrayid) {
    //get id
        id = Integer.parseInt(s);
    }

    //create post object 
    post.setnamePost(namepost);
    post.setText(textpost);
    //this i add in table post value idCat              
    //how add in object post category id?
    //post.add(???);

    try{
    //and i add, bellow add method
        Factory.getInstance().getPostDAO().addPost(post);
        response.sendRedirect("indexadmin");
    }catch(Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }finally{
                        if(session!=null && session.isOpen())
                            session.close();
                    }
```

like this i add method

```
public void addPost(Posts post) {
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(post);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch(Exception e) { outputError("addPost", e);
        } finally{ closeSession(session); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDCAT", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Category category;
```

Why do you have `insertable=false` ? This basically says that the Post entity it's not responsible for the insert action on the Category entity. Try remove `insertable=false` or change it to `insertable=true` ( which I think is by default ).